# Material UI modifier class styles using props not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Trying to set the colors based on props for an inner selector ('&$selected' and '&:hover'). But the colors are not applied, though I can see the class related to selected being applied.

```js
const getColor = (color, theme) => {
  return color === 'primary'
    ? theme.palette.primary.contrastText
    : color === 'secondary'
    ? theme.palette.secondary.contrastText
    : theme.palette.action.active;
};

const getBgColor = (color, theme) => {
  return color === 'primary'
    ? theme.palette.primary.main
    : color === 'secondary'
    ? theme.palette.secondary.main
    : theme.palette.action.active;
};

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    textTransform: 'none',

    // This does not apply the set colors
    '&$selected': {
      color: ({ color }) => getColor(color, theme),
      backgroundColor: ({ color }) =>
        getBgColor(color, theme),
      // This is not applied as well
      '&:hover': {
        backgroundColor: ({ color }) =>
          getBgColor(color, theme),
      },
    },
  },
  selected: {},
}))
```

Comment: Need more code about your component which is using those styles

Comment: Please create a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your problem.